# trying to build simple web app with Google Maps API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, google-maps

I'm trying to build a simple web app using the Google Map API. I haven't decided if I want to use Rails or Django yet. I've been looking for some tutorials, but none have given me really what I'm looking for. Understand, I'm a newbie when it comes to both Rails and Django.

What I want to do is like this:

http://durasupreme.com/dealer-locator

Where you type in a zip code and it returns a map with pins for the locations on a map. I already have the database information, I'm just wondering what the best way to do this. I feel like I have the idea, I know the tools I need to use, but I don't know how to put it all together.

Any help or links to resources would be greatly appreciated.

D

Comment: Yes, I will have that information. It's just going to be a simple directory of businesses in my state. Not a huge data set by any stretch. Getting the Lat and Long should be fairly easy (at least I think so) What are you thinking??

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few useful links if you decide to go for Rails:

- [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/)
- [Railscast about Geocoder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder)
- [Google Maps for Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't have much to do with Django or Rails.  It will be mostly javascript.  Here's a simple implementation outline:

1. Follow the tutorials to get started on google maps api on a static local html file.
2. In javascript write a map_init and add_marker helper functions.
3. When confident, add the link, div, and script tags you wrote to your template.
4. Have your view/controller method get a list of objects from the db.
5. Pass them to the template
6. In the template do a for loop over the object list.

   - inside the loop use the appropriate obj attributes to feed the add_marker helper function.

Comment: OO sounds like a big deal, but if you replace object with the word "thing" does it sound less intimidating?  A thing with attributes, thing.color, thing.title, thing.delete().  From a C point of view it is just a structure with functions.

Comment: Started digging around in the Google Maps API and came across this: code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html which is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the recommendation.